# What is the difference between UserLocale, Systemlocale, InputLocale and KeyboardLocale in Windows?

Tags: windows, language, deployment

What does setting each of the four different "locale" values actually do in Windows? Date format? Currency? Decimal separator? Keyboard layout? CSV-file separator for Excel?

There are four available "Locales" to set when deploying Windows, but I am unable to distiguish between them even after deploying hundreds of systems in several countries. It would be useful to understand what each is for, and TechNet does not explain this clearly anywhere I've found.

- UserLocale
- Systemlocale
- InputLocale
- KeyboardLocale

Comment: The user locale only applies to the current user.  The system local applies to all users.  The keyboard locale applies to the keyboard.  "There are four available locales" - Where do you see these being offered?

Comment: @Ramhound I use these mostly in the customsettings.ini of the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781091.aspx)

Comment: I also find those in registry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\UnattendSettings\International`.

Comment: I made an attempt to answer your question.  As for what the locale defines specifically, well anything that is a regional setting and is handled by the locale (i.e. en-us), far to many things to list everything though.  The default currency Excel uses, unless you change it, is one of those things.

Answer (score 2):

> What does setting each of the four different "locale" values actually
>   do in Windows?

UserLocale is described as the following.

> UserLocale
>
> The user locale to be used with the target operating system. If not
>   specified, the Deployment Wizard uses the user locale configured in
>   the image being deployed.

You also wanted to know what it defined.  It defines the currency, decimal senator, date format, keyboard layout, and anything that would be defined by regional setting.

InputLocale and KeyboardLocale are described as the following.

> [image]

Additionally,

> SystemLocale specifies the default language to use for non-Unicode
>   programs.

Source:

1. [SystemLocale](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766324(v=ws.10).aspx)
2. [Introduction to Toolkit Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781091.aspx#UserLocale)